# url could note get web data response

Tags: ios, json

```
          I am trying to hit this url with json parsing but when i hit with breakpoint there is no data in nslog..
```

In the another parsing it works perfectly but with this url it not works
      String format values are :-kk,8882121456,2015-10-26,123,123,male,02

NSString *urlLoc = @"http://www.vallesoft.com/vlcc_api/bookappointment.php";

```
            NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&mobileno=%@&emailid=%@&dob=%@&password=%@&gender=%@&ref=%@&fbflag=0",goSignUpName,goSignUpMobile,goSignUpEmailId,goSignUpDOB,goSignUpPassword,goSignUpGender,goSignUpReferenceId] ;
            NSData *postData = [requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

            [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlLoc]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
             {

                 if(data.length>0 && connectionError==nil)
                 {


                     responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                     NSLog(@"LOGIN Response ==> %@", responseData);

                     if ([responseData intValue] == 1)
                     {

                         UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thanks" message:@"Registered" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                         [alert show];

                         for(id controller in [self.navigationController viewControllers])
                         {
                             if([controller isKindOfClass : [ViewController class]]){ [self.navigationController popToViewController: controller animated: YES];
                                 break;
                             }
                         }



                     }
                     else if ([responseData intValue] == 2)
                     {
                         UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Already Reegistered" message:@"Please choose other Details" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                         [alert show];
                     }
                     else if (responseData==NULL)
                     {
                         UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"Not Book Try Again!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                         [alert show];
                     }
```

Comment: Could any on give me response???

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: @harshchauhan what is the problem? when I hit your web-service with the given request string... I am getting "2" in response.

Comment: Problem is when i hit then connection is null but when i hit the url on server then is work

Comment: @Rumin-yeah exactly but its not work in my program and no web data are shown

Comment: @harshchauhan I have posted an answer. You can try it.

Comment: `NSURLConnection ` is deprecated on `iOS9`. If you want to do it. You need conform `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` for get the response data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am using the following code for doing it as dummy and it works. You can try it as follow:

```
NSString *urlLoc = @"http://www.vallesoft.com/vlcc_api/bookappointment.php";

NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=harsh&mobileno=8882121782&emailid=hkrajput12@gmail.com&date=2015-10-21&cityname=1&centrename=3&servicename=5&expertname=3&timeslot=15:00 TO 16:00&cuser=hkrajput12@gmail.com&cdate=2015-10-21&timeslotid=15"];

NSData *postData = [requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlLoc]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
             {

                 if(data.length>0 && connectionError==nil)
                 {


                     NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                     NSLog(@"LOGIN Response ==> %@", responseData);

                 }

}];
```

Comment: @harshchauhan glad to help you... :)